# Convert Period in Year/Quarter format to Date (First Day of Quarter)

Tags: postgresql

I would like to take a string in the format 'YYYYQQ' and parse it into a date.  Specifically I would like to parse it into the first date of the quarter.  For example I would like to parse '2016Q2' into '2016-04-01'.

Per the Postgres documentation, "Q (quarter) is ignored by to_date and to_timestamp".  Well frankly I wish it wasn't ignored :) This means this code will return a result I don't want:

```
select to_date('2014q3', 'YYYY\qQ');

**result**
2014-01-01

**desired result**
2014-07-01
```

How could I parse this string to the proper date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 9.4 and greater there is a function that will create a date.

```
make_date(year, month, day)
```

You can use it as follows:

```
make_date(year, quarter * 3 -2 , 1)::date
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [string manipulation functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html) `format()`, `left()` and `right()`:

```
with quarters(q) as (
    values ('2014q1'), ('2015q2'), ('2016q3'), ('2017q4')
)
select format('%s-%s-1', left(q, 4), right(q, 1)::int* 3- 2)::date
from quarters;

   format   
------------
 2014-01-01
 2015-04-01
 2016-07-01
 2017-10-01
(4 rows)
```

Create a function for convenience:

```
create or replace function quarter_to_date(text)
returns date language sql as $$
    select format('%s-%s-1', left($1, 4), right($1, 1)::int* 3- 2)::date
$$;

with quarters(q) as (
    values ('2014q1'), ('2015q2'), ('2016q3'), ('2017q4')
)
select quarter_to_date(q)
from quarters;

 quarter_to_date 
-----------------
 2014-01-01
 2015-04-01
 2016-07-01
 2017-10-01
(4 rows)
```